# PGP encryption using .ASC file.

Tags: encryption, file-encryption

I need to send a important file(i.e.: pdf) to someone. They gave me a .ASC file for encrypting the file i will send. What could be the procedure for encrypting the pdf using that .ASC file? 
Please mention the options by which i can be sure i have encrypted it correctly.

Comment: What is in the .asc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on windows, I use an open-source program called Gpg4win/Kleopatra.

1. Open Kleopatra
2. File > Import certificates... > browse for the .asc file

This will now allow you to encrypt files using that public key.

1. Open Kleopatra
2. File > Sign/encrypt files
3. Browse for .pdf file you wish to encrypt
4. (Follow the prompts) Next > select the certificate that you imported previously > Add > Encrypt > Finish
5. Send them the encrypted file.

Comment: Thanks @james. It was veery helpfull at that time. forgot to let you know. :)